# Terminology for a subset that matches an element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As a strict beginner, I have been warned about getting mired in the natural language terms "inclusion" and "belonging," and this makes perfect sense to me. However, I have a problem about the characterization of "elements" and "subsets" which is related but harder for me to resolve.

For the following set:

*X* = {{1, 2}, 1, 2}

We have the power set:

*P(X)* = {{{1, 2}, 1, 2}, {{1, 2}, 1}, {{1, 2}, 2}, {1, 2}, {{1,2}}, {1}, {2}, {}}

So {1, 2} belongs to *X* and is also included in *X*. However, it seems to me that the {1, 2} which belongs to *X* is somehow different than the {1, 2} that is included in *X*. Note that the {1, 2} that belongs to *X* is an element of that set, while the {1, 2} that is included in *X* is a subset of that set. Is it worthwhile to note this difference, or is there even terminology for this difference? In my title I have said that they "match" but this seems to me to be an inadequate characterization.

Comment: you can use word belongs,who cares in such details?belongs or maybe subset could be

Comment: Your intuition that the two sets are distinct is false in set theories based on $\sf ZFC$, but are true in [some? flavor of] type theory. I don't know nearly enough about type theory to write an answer, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're completely correct. You ask "is it worthwhile to note this difference?" and my answer would be "yes, that's a good thing to have noted for yourself." But in practice, most sets we encounter in math tend to contain just one kind of thing (either numbers, or sets of numbers, or functions, or ...), so this kind of potential confusion seldom arises. It's great that you noticed it, though -- shows you're thinking hard about each new definition you encounter.

Comment: So it sounds like there is not widespread terminology for this sort of occurrence. Likewise there is probably no terminology for an element of a set which is not included in that set.

Comment: I've never encountered such terminology (and I got my PhD in 82!), although I've worked in topology rather than, say, set theory, so maybe there are such terms in general use and I just don't know about them.

Comment: But see @J.P.'s comment below -- apparently in his world, things like this come up a bit more often. Live and learn!

Answer (score 4):

This situation comes up very often in set theory (considered as a subject in its own right), since there the only objects we have are sets. That is, whenever we have a set $x$, all of its elements are sets as well.

So, we might have sets $x$ and $y$ such that $x\in y$ *and* $x\subseteq y$. But $x$ is still the same set, whether considered as an element of $y$ or as a subset of $y$. So, in your example, $\{1,2\}$ is $\{1,2\}$ either way. Both sets have the same elements (1 and 2), so are the same set.

In answer to your question then: They are the same set. The interesting property of being both an element and a subset doesn't have a particular name, since it's relatively simple to just write $\{1,2\}\in X$ and $\{1,2\}\subseteq X$.

But there is some terminology for something closely related. Sometimes the situation occurs that you have a set $x$ with the property that *every* member of it is also a subset of it. In this case, we say that $x$ is *transitive*.

Answer (score 0):

Following J.P.'s considerations, it can be useful to think to an example of not-*pure* set theory (I say *pure* set theory when the only objects of the "universe" are sets).

Take an *army* : it is a set of *brigades*; every brigade in turn is a set of *companies*; every company in turn is a set of *platoons*; every platoon in turn is a set of *soldiers*.

But soldiers a nor more "sets of" : they are *urelements*.

So, each soldier is member of a platoon, of a company, and so on. But soldiers are not subset of anything (in this "model").